# laravel storagepath in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, audio, laravel-storage

In SO, I found the following, which sounded logical, to grab Laravel's storage path in JQUERY:

```
var storagePath = "{!! storage_path() !!}"; // updated and tested
```

However, `storagePath` outputs `C:wamp64wwwldicocostorage`,

e.g. the proper path but without the "/", which is both strange & useless.

Am I not getting it right?
I need to get an audio file (*passed on to JQUERY via Ajax*), so that it can be read like so, via JQUERY:

```
Audio(storagePath +'/' + audiofile);
```

*I have not transcribed the entire JS audio stuff here: I know some instructions are missing...*

So I need to have the proper storage file...

PS: I know at this point I am not using the symlink;

if I do so after I get the storagePath issue sorted, what should this be?

Many thanks